# Online - Workflow returns System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions

In my SharePoint Online I'm running a SharePoint 2013 Workflow each time a new list item is created.

This Workflow breaks role inheritance, then sets permissions for the item using some HTTP calls.

I've followed the guide to run Workflow with elevated privileges, found here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

But I receive this error in response when an user (with "Contribute" as permission level) create a new item in list and the Workflow starts:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you trust the workflow app using the tenant admin account?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Yes, I did. I did it twice because I wasn't able to find a page where to know which workflow app were trusted.

Comment: have a look on this post, again you have to double check if you are using the correct permission while trusting the app... we had the same issue and it ends up with permission. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202776/grant-workflow-app-permission-to-peoplemanager-rest-interface